# Moving footer that disapears when you Reach the End

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, footer

OK my boss just asked to do a moving footer(other than the original static footer) that moves with the page as you scroll down and then disappears when you reach the bottom of the page, i have no idea what so ever any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: How about making the footer fixed and then at the bottom of the page have a div with a higher z-index so the footer effectively goes under this and disappears - this would mean nothing but CSS?

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer?

Comment: It's a comment as I don't know what you have tried so far or what your page looks like and whether you want things like velocity on your footer?

Comment: @Matthew Riches Nice idea, but wouldn't that result in top half of the footer showing as it started to overlap, leaving a gap between the top of the footer and the bottom of the browser window?

Comment: @DarrenCrabb Yeah it would be an ugly transition but with the right measurements it should work. The alternative is to use JS to determine when the footer is at the bottom of the page, OP do you want a JS or CSS solution?

Comment: @Matthew Riches Thanks for the suggestions, anyway if you got a solid idea on how to do i'll be thankful

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) 
       $(".footer").css({"display": "none"});
   else if (!$(".footer").is(":visible"))
       $(".footer").css({"display": "block"});
});
```

```
.footer {
 position:fixed; height:20px; width:100%;
 background:blue; bottom:0; left:0;  z-index:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4WWhf/1/

Answer (score 0):

You really should post some code so people can see what you are trying to achieve.

Try Using a fixed footer to lock it to the screen.

```
.Footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
 }
```

Use javascript to change it to position absolute when you want it to no longer be fixed.
I cant show you code suggestions because I have no idea of your ultimate objective.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the CSS to place the footer in a fixed position:

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Then use jQuery to determine when the bottom of the page has been reached.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    if($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) $("#footer").fadeOut();
})
```

If you need to account for pages that don't scroll you would need additional logic.

But it would be handy if you could explain more your ultimate goal or even show us?

Comment: I cant show you i haven't started yet i was just getting some ideas on how to do it,anyway thanks for your help